# PostgreSQL Created from Beanstalk cannot connect

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I just created the Postgre SQL database (RDS) from Beanstalk configuration, the access permission is public, but unfortunately the access from my local is time out.

[image]

I have tried to destroy my env and recreated the beanstalk env several time but the database issue is still the same (password, username, host url are correct!).

[image]

Can somebody please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, I need to setup the inbound access on security group, because it's a staging so I put **Allow From All** as value.

[image]

[image]